# If $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ then for any $A\subset \mathbb R$, $\mathbb R-f^{-1}(A)=f^{-1}(\mathbb R-A)$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ and $A\subset \mathbb R$. Show that $f^{-1}(\mathbb R-A)=\mathbb R-f^{-1}(A)$

I never got this question when I was reading *Set theory & functions*. But while in **Continuity** there is a Theorem in my book which used this.

Answer (score 2):

$(\subseteq)$ :

Let $x \in f^{-1}(\mathbb{R} \backslash A) .$ Then $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f(x) \notin A .$ Notice that $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and so $x \notin f^{-1}(A)$ follows from $f(x) \notin A .$ Thus $x \in \mathbb{R} \backslash f^{-1}(A)$.

$(\supseteq)$ :

Let $x \in \mathbb{R} \backslash f^{-1}(A) .$ Then $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x \notin f^{-1}(A) .$ Clearly, $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$ and note that $f(x) \notin A$ since $x \notin f^{-1}(A)$. Thus $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}\backslash A$ and therefore $x \in f^{-1}(\mathbb{R} \backslash A)$

Answer (score 0):

The elements of $f^{-1}(\mathbb R-A)$ and the elements of $\mathbb R-f^{-1}(A)$ can both be described simply as the elements $x\in\mathbb R$ that satisfy $f(x)\notin A$. And sets with the same elements are equal.